# how to auto generate number in html?

Tags: javascript, html

hello guys i just want to ask how to auto generate sequence number in html? i have found an answer but i want to start with 0001 and so on. i have tried this

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<input id="demo" type="text">
<script>
var seq=0;
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("demo").value = seq;
}
</script>
```

but it doesn't output 000 on it. And i will save it to database so if i click the button it will output the nextnumber that saved in database. please help me thanks!

Comment: What is the relation to php? There's no supportive code, yet you talk about a database. Your question is unclear.

Comment: just want to know if it is possible to know the last number that saved in database then output it in a textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, then there are a number of ways to format a number in this way. Perhaps the simplest is as follows:

```js
var seq=0;

function myFunction(){
// Increment the value
seq += 1

// The string value that will be displayed
var value = '';

// If sequence is less than 10, prefix with 000
if(seq < 10) {
    value = '000' + seq;
}
// If sequence is less than 100, prefix with 00
else if(seq < 100) {
    value = '00' + seq;
}
// If sequence is less than 1000, prefix with 0
else if(seq < 1000) {
    value = '0' + seq;
}
// Otherwise, just use the value directly
else {
    value = seq;
}

// Display the formatted value (ie prefixed with 0's)
document.getElementById("demo").value = value;

}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<input id="demo" type="text">
```

The general pattern here is to prefix the value that is displayed, with differing numbers of 'zero' characters, based on the value of seq.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <input id="demo" type="text">
    <script>
        var seq = 0;
       
        function myFunction() {
            seq = seq +1;
            number = '0000'.substr(String(seq).length) + seq
            document.getElementById("demo").value = number;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var seq = "000" + 0;
```

Just add like this, you will get zeros before the number

Answer (score 0):

```js
var seq = 0;
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").value = `${++seq}`.padStart(4, '0');
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <input id="demo" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```